# How to Save My User Account and Password in Google App Engine Launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the Google App Engine Launcher to deploy my app to the GAE servers. Is there a way to save my user account and password so I don't have to type it in every time I redeploy?

I'm still in the learning stages of using GAE so typing my 16 odd character password gets tiresome when I redeploy 15+ times per evening.

Comment: Maybe you have a reason to deploy but there is a local server with the SDK.

Comment: I redeploy to work with my live data. I'm the only one who uses the app so I'm not really risking a lot by working on the live version. =)

Comment: OT FYI: You can download your live data to your development server with the python bulkloader tool.  It works even with Java.

Comment: I use AutoIT and it works very good. The solution is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527767/scripting-gae-launcher-with-autoit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [oauth](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth) to save an OAuth2 token so you don't need to keep re-typing your password.

Comment: I changed the answer to this because oauth is (two years later) the preferred method currently. Oauth + a bat file to upload works great.

Comment: This answer lacks practical advice on how to use OAuth with GAE

Comment: The oauth instructions are in the section: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2

Answer (score 21):

You can make a .bat file that has the following text:

```
echo <password> | c:\python25\python.exe "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" --email=username --passin update <directory of app on your pc>
```

(According to GAE docs you cannot specify the password as a command line option)

Comment: Oops. BTW I'm using 2.6 and everything is okay so far.

Comment: @ZuzooVn please be more specific, what details do you need?

Comment: You are my hero! the "echo <password> | " part is genius! :D

Comment: Quite insecure.  [Stuart Langley gave a much better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11964110/94363)

Comment: Much more secure idea is to turn on two-factor authentication and use:
appcfg.py --oauth2_refresh_token=token update yourapp/

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution didn't work for me. Using pipes did

```
echo <password> | c:\python25\python.exe "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" --email=username --passin update <directory of app on your pc>
```

Answer (score 3):

appcfg already does this for you. Per the docs:

> appcfg.py gets the application ID from
>   the app.yaml file, and prompts you for
>   the email address and password of your
>   Google account. After successfully
>   signing in with your account,
>   appcfg.py stores a "cookie" so that it
>   does not need to prompt for a password
>   on subsequent attempts.

If this isn't occurring for you, you might want to try deleting any `.appcfg*` config files.

Comment: The cookie gets wiped after a reboot or a few hours of inactivity.

Comment: In one of my computers this works, in other it doesn't. I couldn't find any `.appcfg*` config files.

Answer (score 3):

Other tips & trick: using command line as below:

To get appcfg.py to accept --password on the command line instead of being prompted for it:

Change: *appengine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py*

add the following in the parser.add_option section:

```
parser.add_option("-p","--password", action="store", dest="password",
                  metavar="PASSWORD", default=None,
                  help="The password")
```

Then modify the GetUserCredentials function:

```
def GetUserCredentials():
  """Prompts the user for a username and password."""
  email = self.options.email
  if email is None:
    email = self.raw_input_fn("Email: ")

  password = self.options.password
  if password is None:
    password = self.raw_input_fn("Password: ")

#      password_prompt = "Password for %s: " % email
#      if self.options.passin:
#        password = self.raw_input_fn(password_prompt)
#      else:
#        password = self.password_input_fn(password_prompt)

  return (email, password)
```

That's it, now you can call:

```
appcfg.py update demos/guestbook --email=email@gmail.com --password=xxxx
```

Ref: http://samalolo.blogspot.com/2009/04/appcfgpy-tweak-to-allow-passing.html

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to say thank you to Friar Broccoli, it's exactly what I was looking for. To clarify for other beginners like myself, my final batch file ended up looking like the following,

```
c:\python27\pythonw.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" --oauth2 update "C:\Users\[username]\[directory]\app.yaml"
```

Worked perfectly, wish this solution was higher up.

Comment: You're a beginner so I'm assuming you've done research into this, but is there a good public demo project for GAE that isn't horribly outdated and also includes things like bat files for uploads? If there isn't then I'll make one.

Answer (score 2):

For windows 7, .appcfg_cookies under C:\Users\username\.appcfg_cookies

Answer (score 1):

You could write a command line script that executes `appcfg.py` to do this.

You can specify the email to use with the `--email=` command line parameter.

You can pass in the password from stdin by using the `--passin` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It's amazingly simple.  Just put this in a batch file:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2  update  "X:\local\path\to\your\app.yaml\file"
```

The first time you run it google will authenticate, after that it's all automatic.