# How do you deploy with OAuth2 from the GAE Launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy my GAE app with the handy launcher, but as my account uses 2-factor authentication, it's being a little difficult:

```
Password for <me>@gmail.com: Use an application-specific password 
instead of your regular account password.
See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833
However, now the recommended way to log in is using OAuth2. See 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth
```

At the above webpage I'm instructed to simply throw `--oauth2` in the options to `appcfg.py`:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 update myapp/
```

If I was on the command line, it would be straightforward, but if I'm using the GAE Launcher, how can I use OAuth2?  The only place I see to add command-line options is for running the app locally, not deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an [application specific password](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833) for this to work - that will mean you can deploy applications using a username/password combination.

Comment: I was trying to acquiesce to their suggestion that `the recommended way to log in is using OAuth2`.

Comment: Yup, this works. The instructions the app spits at you as of today are simply wrong. Do what Felix says and just put in an app specific password in the pwd box!

Comment: Putting an app specific password in the password box upon deployment does not prevent future password prompts.  In fact it prompts me every time now - or am I missing something from OP's post that I don't understand?  In the thread link below it says to use OAuth2 instead of the apps pass... so your advice is contradictory to what's available in the google-app-engine tag universe, would you mind clarifying for me?

Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149914/how-to-save-my-user-account-and-password-in-google-app-engine-launcher