# Scripting GAE launcher with AutoIT?

Tags: google-app-engine, windows-7, autoit

Can AutoIT script GAE launcher so that I don't have to type my password each time I deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoIt can automate the GUI no problem. There are 2 edit boxes (`Edit1` and `Edit2`) so you can practically take the notepad examples and change them a little bit. If you want something running in the background then do something like this as a wrapper around the launcher.

```
Local $sLauncherPath = "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe"

Local $iPid = Run($sLauncherPath)

Local $hWin
While ProcessExists($iPid)
    $hWin = WinWait("Deploy Application to Google", "", 1)

    If $hWin And WinGetProcess($hWin) = $iPid Then
        ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit1", "MyEmail@Domain.com")
        ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit2", "MyPassword123")

        ControlClick($hWin, "", "Button2")

        WinWaitClose($hWin)
    EndIf
WEnd
```

Alternatively, you can deploy the app from the command line.