# Hardcode password into google app engine launcher with text file

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Alot of time is wasted on re-entering password for every deployment in google app engine launcher. Is there a way I can hard code the email and password in their with a text file? I tried editing the appcfg.py but no use. I understand the risks involved in this approach, however I would still like to know.

Comment: You should absolutely not hard code your password into a file if that file will be deployed on your server (I haven't used app engine I don't know if that file gets deployed).

Comment: I am aware of the dangers if that happens

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to use --oauth2 param. This may not work with app engine launcher, but it will defenetely work if you will create custom bash script for deployment. You can read more on [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2) page.

> If you don't want to enter your login credentials, you can use an
>   OAuth2 token instead. This token gives access to App Engine, but not
>   to other parts of your Google account; if your Google account uses
>   two-factor authentication, you'll find this especially convenient. You
>   can store this token to permanently log in on this machine.

If you are Sublime Text user you can add this code into your project config file to be able to deploy with a hotkey like CMD + B or CTRL + B. I'm sure its easy to do for most major code editors.

```
{
  "build_systems":
  [
    {
      "name": "App Engine Deploy",
      "cmd": ["cd $project_path; appcfg.py --oauth2 update ."],
      "shell": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing that with a hotkey but will still get the annoying prompt from the launcher. I am out of options right now so I am going with the "autoit" method I discovered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527767/scripting-gae-launcher-with-autoit. This is working right now and it will do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hard code password directly but I did this trick to attach password to email parameter to hardcode password in bat files

**1.** you must backup YOURAPPENGINEURL/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py.
Then Find following code block in that file

```
  def GetUserCredentials():
  """Prompts the user for a username and password."""
  email = self.options.email
  if email is None:
    email = self.raw_input_fn('Email: ')

  password_prompt = 'Password for %s: ' % email


  if self.options.passin:
    password = self.raw_input_fn(password_prompt)
  else:
    password = self.password_input_fn(password_prompt)

  return (email, password)
```

This code parse email and prompt password at run time.

**2.** replace this code block with following code block

```
  def GetUserCredentials():
  """Prompts the user for a username and password."""
  email = self.options.email
  if email is None:
    email = self.raw_input_fn('Email: ')

  tmp=email.split(':')
  email=tmp[0]
  password=tmp[1]

  return (email, password)
```

Then save your appcfg file.

**3.**  now you can hardcode your password with following command

```
 appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=youremail@gmail.com:YOURPASSWORD update ./
```

**4.** Important fact is that you can only update your app by attaching password to email. app.cfg never prompt for password

Comment: Please check your python code and be sure it is not 
C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py. 
Actual file is 
C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py
here is my working appcfg.py file.
 http://www31.zippyshare.com/v/71228066/file.html

Answer (score -1):

I decided to go with a third party on this issue; utilizing "autoit":

Thank Matt for this

```
Local $sLauncherPath = "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe"
Local $iPid = Run($sLauncherPath)

Local $hWin
While ProcessExists($iPid)
$hWin = WinWait("Deploy Application to Google", "", 1)

If $hWin And WinGetProcess($hWin) = $iPid Then
    ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit1", "MyEmail@Domain.com")
    ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit2", "MyPassword123")

    ControlClick($hWin, "", "Button2")

    WinWaitClose($hWin)
EndIf
WEnd
```