# appcfg ignoring --passin flag

Tags: google-app-engine, appcfg

I'm trying to upload my app to Google AppEngine using appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30 and trying to use the --passin flag:

```
appcfg.sh --passin --email=myemail@email.com --no_cookies  update .
```

However, instead of being asked for the password, a new tab in the browser is being opened, where I get a one-time token. Then I need to use that token with the appcfg to continue updating my app.

This behavior is different in older versions. When I use appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6, for example, with the --passin flag, I'm being asked to enter my password. 
I cannot use the one-time token, since I want to run an automatic script for my upload. How can I make the appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30 use password and not a one-time token?

Answer (score 0):

`ClientLogin` (used to validate with userid and password) was deprecated in 2012 (see http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) and removed 3 years later (i.e several months ago).

Rather, use `--oauth`; see e.g the accepted answer to [How to Save My User Account and Password in Google App Engine Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149914/how-to-save-my-user-account-and-password-in-google-app-engine-launcher) for how to integrate that in a script.